# collision detection of objects in different layer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, game-physics

My 2 objects (player and obstacle) are in different layer and both are adding in GameLayer (main layer). I want to get collision detection of objects of objects (player and obstacle).

I have following code but unfortunate it is not getting collision detection.

```
 CGPoint P_point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[playerLayer.player convertToWorldSpace:playerLayer.player.position]];

CGRect frame_1 = CGRectMake(P_point.x,P_point.y, playerLayer.player.boundingBox.size.width, playerLayer.player.boundingBox.size.height);


CGPoint selfMouPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:self.position];


 if(CGRectContainsPoint( frame_1, selfMouPoint ))
    NSLog(@"Collision");
```

What is wrong with the code? Here is SELF is obstacle object.

Comment: Here is the answer 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019556/cocos2d-how-to-check-for-intersection-between-objects-in-different-layers][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019556/cocos2d-how-to-check-for-intersection-between-objects-in-different-layers